# Decode QR code, from low quality image (with ZBar)

Tags: opencv, qr-code, zbar

I tried to decode QR codes from images like this:

[image]

Based on the [following code](https://github.com/ayoungprogrammer/WebcamCodeScanner/blob/master/main.cpp),

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <zbar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace zbar;

//g++ main.cpp /usr/local/include/ /usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_highgui.2.4.8 -lopencv_core.2.4.8

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

   // cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,800);
   // cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,640);

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }


    ImageScanner scanner;  
      scanner.set_config(ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);  

   double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
   double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }

        Mat grey;
        cvtColor(frame,grey,CV_BGR2GRAY);

        int width = frame.cols;  
        int height = frame.rows;  
        uchar *raw = (uchar *)grey.data;  
        // wrap image data  
        Image image(width, height, "Y800", raw, width * height);  
        // scan the image for barcodes  
        int n = scanner.scan(image);  
        // extract results  
        for(Image::SymbolIterator symbol = image.symbol_begin();  
        symbol != image.symbol_end();  
        ++symbol) {  
                vector<Point> vp;  
        // do something useful with results  
        cout << "decoded " << symbol->get_type_name()  << " symbol \"" << symbol->get_data() << '"' <<" "<< endl;  
           int n = symbol->get_location_size();  
           for(int i=0;i<n;i++){  
                vp.push_back(Point(symbol->get_location_x(i),symbol->get_location_y(i))); 
           }  
           RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(vp);  
           Point2f pts[4];  
           r.points(pts);  
           for(int i=0;i<4;i++){  
                line(frame,pts[i],pts[(i+1)%4],Scalar(255,0,0),3);  
           }  
           //cout<<"Angle: "<<r.angle<<endl;  
        }  

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The naive ZLib approach fails 100%. But the zxing barcode scanner app can decode it from the computer screen, so it's definitely contains all the necessary information.

Any idea how to make the scanning more robust?

Comment: what/where is the error?

Comment: There is no error, it simply detects no symbol. (it does not find any qr code)